# HTML anchor conflicts with express router

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'd like to use the bootstrap tab-list in my project. While it contains anchors point to the sub-panel of the list. These anchors became invalid when I set the express router. The HTML code is like:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a class="allerta" style="font-size:15px;" 
    href="/#overview" aria-controls="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
 <ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active allerta" id="overview" style="
   margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;font-size:18px">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

This href="/#overview" didn't point to the tabpanel anymore after I set up the express router. Instead it points to a empty page which url is "localhost:3000/#/overview". While if I delete the "/" before overview. It will conflict with the $routeProvider in Angularjs. The js file was as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Try using the Angular version of Bootstrap (using Directives instead) https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs

Comment: @Teknotica Thanks for the tip! Seem to be a good solution here.